# Neo4j webadmin - wrong dashboard data

Tags: neo4j

I have crated a new database from scratch and I loaded there one single type of node. There are no relationships. Each node has two properties. For all these properties the values are not null.
Here is the math I cannot understand in the webadmin dashboard.

nodes:      19 798 966
   properties: 25 440 880
   relationships: 0
   relationship types :0

I was expecting the number of properties to be 19 798 966 x 2 = 39 597 932

However when query the database, the results are:

```
$ MATCH (n) WHERE has(n.woka_id) RETURN count (n);
count (n)
19 798 966
```

and

```
$MATCH (n) WHERE has(n.woka_title) RETURN count (n);
count (n)
19798966
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

webadmin doesn't really report counts, indeed the highest ID in use is reported. Since multiple properties are stored internally in the same block you'll see misleading numbers there. To validate:

```
MATCH (n) where has(n.woka_title) and has (n.woka_id) RETURN count(n) == 19798966
```

should return `true`.

Comment: In this case, in my opinion,  the label should be changed. It should say Last ID used instead of Relationships. Information displayed should be correct and not misleading. When we use an online banking system they are telling the money currently existing in the account and not the number of transactions performed. Or the algorithm should be changed and count the number of relationships. Hope the number of nodes is telling the number of nodes and not the Last ID used for them. I know that in the relational databases world to fetch the next value of a sequence is much faster than select count...

Comment: Feel free to raise an github issue on  this.